# Как создать стек LEMP c Yii2 advanced?

Tags: yii2, vagrant, lemp

Развернул ubuntu/trusty64 с nginx, установил php7.1, mysql, установил фреймворк yii2-advanced, и уже настроил приложения. Запушил на github, однако второй участник нашей команды когда клонирует репозиторий, не видит в нём php и mysql?

Можно ли как-то собрать это всё в один флакон, чтобы не пришлось отдельно самостоятельно cтавить php и mysql?

---

Есть замечательный репозиторий со сборкой, но это для wordpress, для yii2 не испытывал 
https://github.com/uptimizt/vagrant-lemp

Comment: попробуйте docker

Comment: Нет, но можно приложение развернуть через docker, в этом случаи на хостовой машине не нужен будет php и mysql, все развернется в докере. Более подробно можете узнать здесь https://www.docker.com/
Так же можете развернуть с помощью тулзы Docker Compose